# How do I make a div (with empty content) be the same height as that of a div with content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.bg-text {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    top:30em;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    height: fit-content;
}
.para{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    top:30em;
    left: 70%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="bg-text">
        <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u></h4><br>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="date">Select date :</label><br></li>
            <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><br><br>
            <li><label for="page">Enter Page No</label><br></li>
            <input type="number" id="page" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><br><br>
            <li><label for="link">News link (if any)</label><br></li>
            <input type="text" id="link" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><br><br>
            <span>Choose the required mode of file input</span>
            <li><div class="mb-3" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 2px solid white; padding: 5px;">
                <input type="radio" id="sel_scan" name="doc" value="scanning">
                <button id="scan" onclick="startScan()" disabled>Scan document</button><br><br>
                <div style="width: 100%;"> 
                    <input type="radio" id="myfile" name="doc" value="choosing">
                    <input type="file" id="Myfile"  accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png" disabled>
                </div>
            </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="para">
        <div class="container">
            <img src='#' style='height:100%; width:100%'>
            <!--<embed src='#' style='height:100%; width:100%'> div becomes smaller if  I attach a pdf-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid gap-*" id="but">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

My problem is that, although the height of the first div is static, the height of the second div keeps on changing, depending on the `src` of the `<img>`. I want the second div to have the exact same height as that of the first div regardless of whatever `src` I give, be it `pdf` or `img` and whatever device is used to view the page.

---

**EDIT**: Tried this code in my `js`, didn't work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var left=document.getElementsByClassName('bg-text')[0].clientHeight;
    document.getElementsByClassName('para')[0].clientHeight=left;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

tried to set img/pdf `height` to `inherit`? Fix container width & height, using container adjust the size of image as per requirements.

```
    <div class="para">
    <div class="container" style='height:50%; width:50%>
        <img src='#' style='height:inherit; width:inherit'>
        <!--<embed src='#' style='height:inherit; width:inherit'> div becomes smaller if  I attach a pdf-->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something here but can you not just use flex?
`display: flex`

Comment: Tried with `flex`, it yields the same result

Comment: @Abhishek https://codepen.io/craig_codes/pen/abEOBrK

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexbox or grid for your main layout and reserve position only for "special" cases. If you remove position: absolute and add display flex to the container element it will default to equal height columns.

```css
.bg-text {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.para{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="bg-text">
        <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u></h4><br>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="date">Select date :</label><br></li>
            <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><br><br>
            <li><label for="page">Enter Page No</label><br></li>
            <input type="number" id="page" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><br><br>
            <li><label for="link">News link (if any)</label><br></li>
            <input type="text" id="link" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><br><br>
            <span>Choose the required mode of file input</span>
            <li><div class="mb-3" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 2px solid white; padding: 5px;">
                <input type="radio" id="sel_scan" name="doc" value="scanning">
                <button id="scan" onclick="startScan()" disabled>Scan document</button><br><br>
                <div style="width: 100%;"> 
                    <input type="radio" id="myfile" name="doc" value="choosing">
                    <input type="file" id="Myfile"  accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png" disabled>
                </div>
            </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="para">
        <div class="container">
            <img src='#' style='height:100%; width:100%'>
            <!--<embed src='#' style='height:100%; width:100%'> div becomes smaller if  I attach a pdf-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid gap-*" id="but">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="para">
    <div class="container">
        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-grid gap-*" id="but">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).